# Get variable only after getting a response from POST

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

How can I set a variable in my component, only after I get response from POST request?

component.ts code:

```
formSubmit() {
    this.sent = this.submitProvider.sendByPost(this.form);
    this.formSent = this.submitProvider.formSent;
}
```

service/provider.ts:

```
sendByPost(form) {
    return this.http.post("http://app.api.com/mail/", form, httpOptions)
        .subscribe(
            data => (
                this.formSent = true,
            ), // success path
            error => (console.log(error)), // error path,
            () => this.formSent = true
        )
}
```

Comment: Move the subscribe to the component as shown in the docs here: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amm maybe you will do this one 
Your service

```
sendByPost(form) {
    return this.http.post("http://app.api.com/mail/", form, httpOptions).toPromise() // you don't need observable here
  }
```

and then subscribe for it into component

`this.submitProvider.sendByPost(this.form).then(res => this.formSent = true)`

or remain your observable and do the same

```
   sendByPost(form) {
        return this.http.post("http://app.api.com/mail/", form, httpOptions) // you don't need observable here
      }
```

and component will be

```
this.submitProvider.sendByPost(this.form).subscribe(res => this.formSent = true)
```